# Equate 2 objects - differently each time?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a class :

```
  public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int  age { get; set; }
    }

        Person p1 = new Person() { age=1, name="a" };
        Person p2 = new Person() { age = 1, name = "b" };
```

I want to do something like

```
p1.equals(p2)
```

but by age **or** by name

*I don't mean in a way of adding to dictionary ( and use Iequatable...)*

the Equals method Doesnt take any Helper inside it ...

[image]

is there any way that i can send him my specific helper class just like :

```
   Dictionary<PersonForDictionary, int> dct2 =
 new Dictionary<PersonForDictionary, int>(new helperClass()); // here helperclass is a class which I gave him - and told the dictionary how to equate objects....
```

Im looking for a **similar** solution when equating objects. ( not in dictionary mode).

Comment: Do you mean when you call it the first time it should check for name equality, the second time for age equality, then again for name and so on?

Comment: if i transfer him a comparer object of name so do it by name , same for age...( if i trasnfer him a comparer objkect for age so do it by age...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be, may be also like make different implementations of `IComparable`.
For example:

```
public class Person
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public int  age { get; set; }

   pulbic int ComparePerson(Person person, IComparable comparer)
   {
     return comparer.Compare(this, person);
   } 
}
```

after implement different classes:

```
public class PersonNameComparer : IComparer
{
}
```

or another

```
public class PersonAgeComparer : IComparer
{
}
```

and use it inside:

```
Person p1 = new Person() { age=1, name="a" };
Person p2 = new Person() { age = 1, name = "b" };

p1.Compare(p2, new PersonNameComparer ());
p1.Compare(p2, new PersonAgeComparer ());
```

Comment: Well it would have to be an `IEqualityComparer` though (preferably strongly typed).

Comment: @Jeff Mercado. Yes, the answer was about just to provide an idea of possibility of the behavior injection. +1

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a comparer so you can do your custom comparisons?  Well ultimately you'd want to create a class that implements the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface for each of the comparisons you want to do.  Or you could create one class that could project your objects into the fields you want to compare...

You could do something like this:

```
var lengthComparer = ProjectionEqualityComparer.Create((String s) => s.Length);
Console.WriteLine(lengthComparer.Equals("foo", "bar"));  // true
Console.WriteLine(lengthComparer.Equals("biz", "baaz")); // false

var nameComparer = ProjectionEqualityComparer.Create((Person p) => p.Name);
var dict = new Dictionary<Person, int>(nameComparer);
```

And the actual implementations:

```
// helper class to make creating the comparers easier
public static class ProjectionEqualityComparer
{
    public static ProjectionEqualityComparer<TSource, TKey> Create<TSource, TKey>(Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        return new ProjectionEqualityComparer<TSource, TKey>(selector, comparer);
    }
}

// the actual comparer
public class ProjectionEqualityComparer<TSource, TKey> : EqualityComparer<TSource>
{
    private Func<TSource, TKey> selector;
    private IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer;
    public ProjectionEqualityComparer(Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        this.selector = selector;
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    }

    public override bool Equals(TSource x, TSource y)
    {
        var xKey = selector(x);
        var yKey = selector(y);
        return comparer.Equals(xKey, yKey);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(TSource source)
    {
        var key = selector(source);
        return key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to just add a method for the type of comparsion you want to do.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public bool SameAge(Person otherPerson)
    {
        return Age == otherPerson.Age;
    }

    public bool SameName(Person otherPerson)
    {
        return Name == otherPerson.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create two comparers, one by name and another by age, and pass it as you need it? Do it like this:

```
class NameComparer: IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if(x.Name < y.Name)
            return -1;
        else if (x.Name == y.Name)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Do the same for age.

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do. can you shouw me how ?